# Seeding rails project with Json file

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm at a lost and my searches have gotten me nowhere.

In my seeds.rb file I have the following code

```
require 'json'

jsonfile = File.open 'db/search_result2.json'
jsondata = JSON.load jsonfile
#jsondata = JSON.parse(jsonfile)

jsondata[].each do |data|
  Jobpost.create!(post: data['title'],
                  link: data['link'],
                  image: data['pagemap']['cse_image']['src'] )
end
```

Snippet of the json file looks like this:

```
  {
    "kind": "customsearch#result",
    "title": "Careers Open Positions - Databricks",
    "link": "https://databricks.com/company/careers/open-positions",
    "pagemap": {
      "cse_image": [
        {
          "src": "https://databricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/careeers-new-og-image-sept20.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Fixed jsondata[].each to jasondata.each. Now I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: Change `data['pagemap']['cse_image']['src']` to `data['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src']` because `cse_image` is an array and it seems like you want to read its first (and only) entry.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I also had a json line that didn't have data for data['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src'] that I deleted to make this run. Hope that helps anyone that has similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

`jsondata[]` says to call the [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) method with no arguments on the object in the `jsondata` variable. Normally `[]` would take an index like `jsondata[0]` to get the first element or a start and length like `jsondata[0, 5]` to get the first five elements.

You want to call the [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) method on `jsondata`, so `jsondata.each`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made the edit to jsondata.each, now I'm getting a TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: @JosephLee To help, we'd need to know the line number of the error and the associated code. Often that means you're trying to use a String as an index into an Array. `array['string']`. Check what `data` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

So this is very specific to what you have posted:

```rb
require 'json'

file = File.open('path_to_file.json').read
json_data = JSON.parse file

p json_data['kind'] #=> "customsearch#result"
# etc for all the other keys
```

now maybe the json you posted is just the first element in an array:

```json
[
  {}, // where each {} is the json you posted
  {},
  {},
  // etc
]
```

in which case you will indeed have to iterate:

```rb
require 'json'

file = File.open('path_to_file.json').read
json_data = JSON.parse file

json_data.each do |data|
  p data['kind'] #=> "customsearch#result"
end
```